# Match feature diagrams with temporal fuction in QGIS

Tags: qgis, vector, timemanager, histogram, diagram

I am trying to create a time-dependent visualisation using a heatmap-styled points layer and a points layer with values to show at specific locations. The heatmap one shows occurrences over the territory and the other shows measurement stations. For this last one, I would like to display the values using diagrams (histograms) at each time step. However, when activating the diagram, it shows the diagrams of all features at once and does not respect the @map_start_time / @map_end_time variables from the timemanager. Can anyone help me make the diagram to show only the time-related feature, instead of all (see image)?

[image]

So far, I have not found any exactly related question, except this one ([QGIS Diagrams using rule based categories?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/337794/qgis-diagrams-using-rule-based-categories)), which did not address the exact problem I have and did not seem to have been resolved. Also, as it was posted years ago, there might have been some changes.

The idea is for it to show two or more fields of data for the feature visible at a certain time step. I am using QGIS 3.24.1.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to a tip from Alexandre Neto https://gis.stackexchange.com/users/6191/alexandre-neto, I realized that you can actually set diagram visibility, and in your case using time variables. This is the basic expression that I set and worked, but probably it can be refined:

```
"datatimefield" > @map_start_time and "datatimefield" < @map_end_time
```